# Using CTRL with bash

Tags: macos, bash

Coming from year on Windows, I swapped <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> buttons.

On bash I used to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> for jumping to the beginning/end of line. But, since I swapped the buttons I need press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

How I make bash recognize back my beloved key combination?

Comment: Long term it's **far** simpler to just get used to the difference, than try to patch it.

Comment: If you figure this out, let me know. :)

Comment: @Vladimir Eventually I did what Tetsujin proposed :(

Comment: I'm going to keep resisting ;)

Comment: @Vladimir You could probably achieve the result you want with a third party app like Keyboard Maestro. However, I cannot emphasise enough on used default shortcuts, because Mac shortcuts are somewhat intuitive for which you'll start to get a feel for after some time. Cherish the best of both worlds.

Comment: @user14492 Cool! Thanks for the suggestion! +1 Yeah, I agree just learning it would be the best option for most people. In my case personally it will be confusing because I'm a programer and I have to use my Mac and Windows about 50/50. So having to stop and think about which key combo I need would hurt my productivity too much. Haha :)